# Does file_get_content() return the same binary data as the original file

Tags: php, blob, file-get-contents

The question is in the title. I am having trouble in blob images display since a few days.
When i look to binary datas of the displayed images (who display with the broken symbol, actually they dont really display), i get different raw data form orginal .jpg and the file_get_content()  binary file generated.
Here is a related post orm yesterday with some more explanations.

--> [mysql blob image displaying with php/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868343/mysql-blob-image-displaying-with-php-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is : yes. There's no reason the contents should be different. Your problem is probably in another castle.

Comment: I totally agree with you... Maybe when the return of file_get_content() goes into the Mysql BLOB it get modified? Check my link and tell me if you see anything suspect from my code

Comment: Or maybe it can come from the headers?

Comment: If you were sitting in my office, and ask the same question. I would ask that you install Charles HTTP Proxy, and I'd go over the exact response from that url to look for something suspicious.

Comment: Hum, I already have the devtool from Chrome who allow me to check headers, but thanks for your answers. Problem is that I dont understand really well the meaning of all those headers things, I gonne check it out on the internet.

Comment: Having this return after uploading my image:

------WebKitFormBoundaryFxYwOIY8tJCfDekb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="original.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

------WebKitFormBoundaryFxYwOIY8tJCfDekb--
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:2872
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Thu, 09 Aug 2012 09:36:11 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=62
Server:Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.3`code`

Comment: @Mayerz Can you access the image file on the server (and read it?). That way we'd know whether it's the reading or the writing which is the problem.

Comment: I apologize I'm having trouble in formatting thoses comments :/ It didnt work the same way as question's posting.

Comment: Yes I can read it.
It is stored in my DB as a blob, I can access it. But when i read it adding .jpg i didn't work

Comment: Oh god, the original image binary datas, and the ones from my DB are the same. So the problem is coming from the display process, because then when it display I only see the broken-image icon, and when I download it, the binary data isnt the same.

Comment: Ok founded out the solution by using the data URI, see here if you have same problem as me http://stackoverflow.com/a/2070625/1585121. Have a nice day!