# How do I display the image I got from fread()?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php: recreate and display an image from binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data)

I want to display in my page the image I got from this code:

```
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
```

How do I display it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to print out image's content and set proper header depends on the filetype.

Example:

```
<?php

$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $contents;
```

Comment: can you give explicit example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a file that is outputting HTML, and within that page you would like to show an image, you need to use the `<img>` tag. You can call another file that does what the other poster suggested to output the contents. But the `Content-Type` you would output depends on the image MIME type. If it's a PNG file, then you would use a different header parameter:

```
<?php

$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

header('Content-Type: image/png'); // or image/gif, depending on what $filename is.
echo $contents;
```

Your other option is to output this image inline using [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

Here is an example:

```
<?php
// take note that this is for PNG files - just change it to JPG or GIF depending on whatever your image is
$filename = 'image.png';
echo 'The following image is a PNG file... <img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)).'" />';
?>
```

Comment: Actually @rationalboss, you likely need to incorporate part of your earlier answer and base64_encode($contents) rather than base64_encode($filename)

Comment: makes sense, i updated my answer.