# PHP display png image from binary file

Tags: php, image-processing, binary, png

I have binary file where is stored image, i try get this image, but display only black color image, what can be wrong with my code or binary file.

```
<?php
function LoadPNG ($imgname) {
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng ($imgname); 

    if (!$im) { 
        $im= imagecreate (150, 30); 
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc= imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
        imagefilledrectangle ($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        imagestring ($im, 1, 5, 5, "Error loading $imgname", $tc);
    }
    return $im;
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$img = LoadPNG('452');

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

with this code I get I error that can't load file

File: [testams.serveriai.lt.lazdynas.serveriai.lt/452](http://testams.serveriai.lt.lazdynas.serveriai.lt/452)
Script:  [testams.serveriai.lt.lazdynas.serveriai.lt/crypt.php](http://testams.serveriai.lt.lazdynas.serveriai.lt/crypt.php)

Comment: This may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data

Comment: I can see the "Error loading 452" image on your script page in Safari. Is it only breaking in a particular browser?

Comment: @MattGibson it't in all browsers

Comment: @Pooshonk I think my binary file is not coded in base64

Comment: Did you try fetching the file via php? (f.e. using http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: @Chris try, but get only symbols

Comment: Can you try getting the file via file_get_contents and use ``imagecreatefromstring`` instead of ``imagecreatefrompng`` ?

Comment: Do you get any helpful errors if you stop suppressing the error output from `imagecreatefrompng` with `@`? Do you see the right file path if you print out @imgname? (You may need to temporarily stop sending the Content-Type header for easier debugging; leaving it in will probably prevent you seeing errors in the browser.)

Comment: @MattGibson I get this  `Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '452' is not a valid PNG file in /home/testams/domains/testams.serveriai.lt/public_html/crypt.php on line 3
�PNG  IHDR��,uPLTE���U��~iIDAT(�c` ������������&��@���N�-�%y�)�猧,��LWf�LY��!'Ш�S�t`���ӂe�̓Pu�������`I���@�߀��D����2߇6sIEND�B`�'

Comment: Guess imagecreatefrompng wants the correct image header which is not given. You're only outputting the source of the image file (on the given link) and not the image itself, which is definitely a header problem. imagecreatefromstring could work in this case or adding the correct header to the script that outputs the image.

Comment: What is the path you're passing in $imgname? Are you loading it as a URL (using http://...)? If so, you need to fix the headers the web server sends; it's encoding your file as `text/plain`. It might be enough simply to rename it as 452.png; many web servers will guess the Content-Type they should send based on file extension.

Comment: Your PNG is invalid, if you open it with any image viewer or image editor, it won't even be able to open it, so how in the world would PHP be able to ?

Comment: Also -- having grabbed your image file, it looks invalid. ImageMagick's `identify` says "improper image header". Are you *sure* that's a valid PNG you've got there? If it loads okay for you locally, then something's killing it on the way out of the door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PNG image is corrupt, it has a `\n` character instead of `\r\n`, ([byte position 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)) typically a problem arising from FTP transfering a binary image in text mode from Windows to Unix.

Before messing with PHP, you should check simply that the image is OK, eg adding the .png extension, placing it in a visible folder (in the web server) and browsing it.