# How can I display binary image data as an Image in PHRETS

Tags: rets

I am using http://otw.rets.interealty.com/Login.asmx/Login
I am getting image as Binay Data. How can I display a binary data from RETS as an Image.
Here is my code

```
$sysid = $data['sysid'];
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $sysid, "*", 1);
echo $photos[0]['Data'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHRETS documentation for [GetObject](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject), the last argument in GetObject, $location, can either be a "0" or "1". "1" returns the image's URL string and "0" returns the binary image data.

**#1 Encoding the image data and outputting to browser without saving to a file. From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data)**

```
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $sysid, "*", 0);
foreach ($photos as $photo) 
{

    if ($photo['Success'] == true) 
    {
        $contentType = $photo['Content-Type'];
        $base64 = base64_encode($photo['Data']); 
        echo "<img src='data:{$contentType};base64," . $base64 . "' />";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "({$photo['Content-ID']}-{$photo['Object-ID']}): {$photo['ReplyCode']} = {$photo['ReplyText']}<br />";
    }

}
```

**#2 Saving the image to a file and then displaying it. [From PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject#usage-examples)**

```
$photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", $sysid, "*", 0);
foreach ($photos as $photo) 
{

    if ($photo['Success'] == true) 
    {
        file_put_contents("image-{$listing}-{$number}.jpg", $photo['Data']);
        echo "<img src='image-{$listing}-{$number}.jpg' />";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "({$photo['Content-ID']}-{$photo['Object-ID']}): {$photo['ReplyCode']} = {$photo['ReplyText']}<br />";
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using http://otw.rets.interealty.com Ottawa Real Estate Board. Do you know how to do pagination in this? "Limit" => "10" is working but "Offset" is not working

Comment: @Minu - Check with your RETS server as offset may not be supported by your RETS server. If my post answered your question please mark it as answered.

Comment: Do you know how to use Unlimited Key Index in PHRETS?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the content-type of the results/data you get back. I would save each file with there respective type (.jpg, .bmp) then reference the saved file in you PHP code.

https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetObject

Answer (score 0):

There's some good information in these answers already.

To address your later question, the Interealty server does not support pagination.  To use Key Index, you must:

1) use RETS/1.7.2 or later
2) specify Limit => NONE in your SearchRequest
3) give only key index identified fields in your Select parameter within the SearchRequest

If you get those 3 things right, the server should suspend its records-per-response limit.