# PHP - how do i read the picture value and make it viewable by browser?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have JPEG/PNG small file which is stored in the mysql database field picture as following:

```
  $fdata = '';
  if (isset($_FILES['picture']) && $_FILES['picture']['size'] > 0) {
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];  
    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $fdata = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $fdata = addslashes($fdata);
    fclose($fp);
    //$sl = "INSERT INTO image (image)VALUES ( '$data')", $connection);
    print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";        
  } else {
    print "No image selected/uploaded";        
  }

  // Update the table 
  $this->db->update('users', 
                    array('password' => $_POST['password'], 
                          'picture' => $fdata), 
                    array('username=?' => $ouser ));
```

But problem is now how do i output that "picture field" value from the database into real picture for web browsers?

EDIT 1:

Simply echo does not render the picture in browser

[image]

EDIT 2:

[image]

```
  public function pictureshowAction() {  
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $this->db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();        
    $ouser = $_GET['ousername'];

    $sql = "select *From users where username='{$ouser}' limit 1";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
    if (count($result) > 0 ) {
      $picture  = $result[0]['picture'];     
      //$content = $picture; 
      $content = stripslashes($picture);
    } else {
      $content = '';
    }

    //echo $content;    

    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
            ->setBody($content)
            ->sendResponse();    
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: recreate and display an image from binary data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy, let's say your content type was `png` you first need to send a proper header to browser

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

Then simply output your picture content

```
echo $pictureContentFromDatabase;
```

What your screenshot shows is caused by the fact that you did not send a proper Content Type header telling the browser what your server is sending is an image, once you fix that it will be fine. And you dont have to `addslashes` for output, that will render the image useless. So echo the content without `addslashes`

Comment: So i have to remove the addslashes from $pictureContentFromDatabase right? e.g: 
    `$this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
            ->setBody($pictureContentFromDatabase)
            ->sendResponse();`

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2 (code that i am trying), i tried to echo with image/jpg but the browser not showing expected picture shown on left

Comment: Now that's another issue as long as the image is displaying :) Will have to do more research to find out why the resolution is different than expected.

Comment: NO - i mean on my right side the image is not showing at all its a small tiny image box showing in Google chrome, but the expected image should be shown which is on the left side.

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump($content);`?

Comment: Its working now. i have to store it as base64_encode e.g: `// not this $fdata = addslashes($fdata); but this 
        $fdata = base64_encode($fdata);` and then show in the browser as `echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64," . $content . "' />";`