# PHP Image from URL

Tags: php

I have the following url which returns an image in the body, How would I assign that image to a variable so that I could save it or use it within my code?

> https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQGOM3p0fHNkwQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1556755200&v=beta&t=qeQFKYXpev2ZW3hmP1ODDPd3DYPWvl-GaUnPSZG-aQA

The following code returns noting:

```
<?php
     $url = "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQGOM3p0fHNkwQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=1556755200&v=beta&t=qeQFKYXpev2ZW3hmP1ODDPd3DYPWvl-GaUnPSZG-aQA";
     $image = file_get_contents($url);
     echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: We need some code here

Comment: `How would I assign that image to a variable so that I could save it or use it within my code` --- you already did.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($image);` show you?

Comment: Such a CDN might reject requests it does not think come from a “regular” browser … so I’d start with specifying a User-Agent request header that mimics that of a current, popular browser. (If you don’t know how to do that using file_get_contents, please research.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: recreate and display an image from binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to view an image from a URL, just put that url in the `src` attribute of an `img` element like this : 
`echo '<img src="' . $url . '"/>';`

otherwise, if you have to view it from the fetched data of that url, then your question have been answered here: 
[php: recreate and display an image from binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data)  (specifically @Krab's answer)